# Natural Language Generation usage with Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: nlp, botframework, chatbot, nlg, nlu

I would need help to understand if any use case is developed using MS bot framework with any NLG capabilities. I understand LUIS has NLP and NLU but not NLG.

Either Azure Chatbot is developed with any NLG such as Turing-NLG?

Comment: As of now, there is no provision of NLG capabilities with LUIS(or on the roadmap). As stated below, the given sample is experimental. Having said that, you can provide this idea in the Cognitive Services [feedback](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-general-feedback) and the team would have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It's an experimental feature in Microsoft Bot Framework, which is under preview. You can refer to the documentation and samples here - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/language-generation